# how to send typing notification using xmpp openfire

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

i am developing chat application i want to send the recipient "is typing" when i type a message does any one has idea how to do this using xmpp framework and open fire as server.

below is my code

```
-(void)sendChatStateNotification: (NSString *)strState
{
     NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
     NSXMLElement *chatStatus=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:strState xmlns:xmlns_chatstates];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:chatWithUser];
    [message addChild:chatStatus];
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self sendChatStateNotification:@"composing"];
}
```

i am still not getting the notification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For sending Typing State

```
NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue: toID];

NSXMLElement *composing = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"composing"];
[composing addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"];

[message addChild:composing];

[xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

At Receiving Side

```
if ([message hasComposingChatState] == YES)
```

Check this condition and use it proper with your typing indication.

Comment: take a look at this extension category - XMPPMessage+XEP_0085

Comment: but the bigger challenge is how will you remove "typing..." from label you set

Comment: where we can check this state ?

Comment: @jaskiratjd in the *delegate method of receiving message*